# Is there a way to combine two ajax.load calls to the same URL

Tags: jquery

I have two .load(URL selector) calls to the same URL, but different selectors.

Is there a way to combine them so there is only one call to the URL, like storing the load results into a string, $('<div>'), and then pulling the two parts out later?

Here is what I have now:

```
  $("#RECENT").load("HoursApp.php?job_id="+jobid+" #RECENT >*");
  $("#TASKS").load("HoursApp.php?job_id="+jobid+" #TASKS >*")
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
  var recent = $("#RECENT");
  var tasks = $("#TASKS");
  var div = $("<div>");

  div.load("HoursApp.php?job_id="+jobid+" #MainPanelBottom");

  recent.html(div.find(" #RECENT >*"));
  tasks.html(div.find(" #TASKS >*"));
```

Comment: `?job_id=$job_id&command=RECENT+TASKS`. you can send over any url you want. if you want multiple "jobs", then send the commands to start those jobs, and mod the server-side stuff to handle multiple jobs. you can then return the data as a simple object. `$data['task1'] = blahblahblah; $data['task2'] = blahblahblah;`

Comment: Can't you just make one request which returns an associative array with all the stuff you need?

Comment: I could have done anything if the idea wasn't to just add a bit of javascript (have an onchange to pull back the same page I already have with just a tweek for the change and then put the two pieces that would have changed into the existing page) and leave the server code otherwise alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `$.get()` of the content and then find the #RECENT and #TASKS parts of the content and put each piece in the div of choice.

Something like this:

```
$.get("HoursApp.php?job_id="+jobid).done(function(data) {
    var raw = $(data);
    $("#RECENT").empty().append(raw.find("#RECENT").children());
    $("#TASKS").empty().append(raw.find("#TASKS").children());
});
```